# How to count JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "38",
        "article_id": "16",
        "news_event": "625",
        "language": "en",
        "channel_partner_id": "625",
        "title": "Test",
        "show_logo": null,
        "description": "test\n\n",
        "schedule": null,
        "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35",
        "link_text": null,
        "guid": null,
        "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:42",
        "website": null,
        "show_hours": null,
        "page_text": null
    },
    {
        "id": "37",
        "article_id": "15",
        "news_event": "625",
        "language": "en",
        "channel_partner_id": "625",
        "title": "Test",
        "show_logo": null,
        "description": "test\n\n",
        "schedule": null,
        "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35",
        "link_text": null,
        "guid": null,
        "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:39",
        "website": null,
        "show_hours": null,
        "page_text": null
    },
    {
        "id": "36",
        "article_id": "14",
        "news_event": "625",
        "language": "en",
        "channel_partner_id": "625",
        "title": "Test",
        "show_logo": null,
        "description": "test\n\n",
        "schedule": null,
        "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35",
        "link_text": null,
        "guid": null,
        "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:35",
        "website": null,
        "show_hours": null,
        "page_text": null
    },
    {
        "id": "35",
        "article_id": "13",
        "news_event": "625",
        "language": "en",
        "channel_partner_id": "625",
        "title": "Test",
        "show_logo": null,
        "description": "test\n\n",
        "schedule": null,
        "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35",
        "link_text": null,
        "guid": null,
        "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:31",
        "website": null,
        "show_hours": null,
        "page_text": null
    }
]
```

How do I count the number of objects in it?

Comment: please format long code. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: please change the title to convey that you want to count elements of an array, not an object.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's an array.
You can parse it (`JSON.parse`), then use the `length` property.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: If that's in source, yes.  The question is very vague.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  Sorry for the poorly formatted code.  And yes, I was a bit vague.

Comment: what if i need it in php?

Answer (score 47):

You can use the following solution to count JSON objects:

```
var jsonObject = {"test1":1,"test2":2};
var keyCount  = Object.keys(jsonObject).length;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this, not for counting elements of an array.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var json = [{ "id": "38", "article_id": "16", "news_event": "625", "language": "en", "channel_partner_id": "625", "title": "Test", "show_logo": null, "description": "test\n\n", "schedule": null, "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35", "link_text": null, "guid": null, "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:42", "website": null, "show_hours": null, "page_text": null }, { "id": "37", "article_id": "15", "news_event": "625", "language": "en", "channel_partner_id": "625", "title": "Test", "show_logo": null, "description": "test\n\n", "schedule": null, "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35", "link_text": null, "guid": null, "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:39", "website": null, "show_hours": null, "page_text": null }, { "id": "36", "article_id": "14", "news_event": "625", "language": "en", "channel_partner_id": "625", "title": "Test", "show_logo": null, "description": "test\n\n", "schedule": null, "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35", "link_text": null, "guid": null, "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:35", "website": null, "show_hours": null, "page_text": null }, { "id": "35", "article_id": "13", "news_event": "625", "language": "en", "channel_partner_id": "625", "title": "Test", "show_logo": null, "description": "test\n\n", "schedule": null, "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35", "link_text": null, "guid": null, "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:31", "website": null, "show_hours": null, "page_text": null}]


//Object.keys(json).length --> USE

for (var i = 1, l = Object.keys(json).length; i <= l; i++) {

}

//by:Jorge Nones, Jales.
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's in the variable `foo`, `foo.length`.

```
var foo = [{...},{...},...];
alert(foo.length);
foo[0].id// 38;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use online JSON editors to verify, for instance, try [JSON Editor Online by josdejong](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This routine counts 4 array elements with 16 attributes per element:

```
var obj = [{ "id": "38", "article_id": "16", "news_event": "625", "language": "en", "channel_partner_id": "625", "title": "Test", "show_logo": null, "description": "test\n\n", "schedule": null, "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35", "link_text": null, "guid": null, "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:42", "website": null, "show_hours": null, "page_text": null }, { "id": "37", "article_id": "15", "news_event": "625", "language": "en", "channel_partner_id": "625", "title": "Test", "show_logo": null, "description": "test\n\n", "schedule": null, "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35", "link_text": null, "guid": null, "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:39", "website": null, "show_hours": null, "page_text": null }, { "id": "36", "article_id": "14", "news_event": "625", "language": "en", "channel_partner_id": "625", "title": "Test", "show_logo": null, "description": "test\n\n", "schedule": null, "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35", "link_text": null, "guid": null, "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:35", "website": null, "show_hours": null, "page_text": null }, { "id": "35", "article_id": "13", "news_event": "625", "language": "en", "channel_partner_id": "625", "title": "Test", "show_logo": null, "description": "test\n\n", "schedule": null, "event_date": "2012-03-09 10:08:35", "link_text": null, "guid": null, "timestamp": "2012-03-09 11:19:31", "website": null, "show_hours": null, "page_text": null}]
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  var ctr=0;
  for (attr in obj[i]) ctr++;
  alert('array['+i+']: ' +ctr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = JSON.parse(this.response);

var length = 0;

for (var k in data) 
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) 
     length++;
```