# How Can I find the length of a json file?

Tags: javascript, json

So I am trying to make a quote system for a chat bot, and I'm having trouble with storing them. I have decided to move away from using a database because of how small scale it is, but I want to be able to constantly add to the file, is there any way I am able to find how many "variables" already in the file? My current file would be setup like this:

```
{ 
 "quote1":"texthere",
 "quote2":"texthere",
 "quote3":"texthere",
 "quote4":"texthere"
}
```

Is there a possible way I am able to figure out how many quotes there are in the file? I am programming in javascript.

Comment: Try storing them in an array [ "texthere", "texthere", "texthere", "texthere" ] and work out how to count the values in there. And [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: This will explain your answer completely...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640190/how-to-count-json-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this (best with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)), but generally you might have more success using an array of objects. I'll go ahead and show two options:

```
const yourJson = require('./path/to/your/json')
const length = Object.keys(yourJson).length
```

Or, using an array of objects:

```
{
  quotes: [
    { id: 1, text: 'this is a quote' },
    { id: 2, text: 'this is a quote' }
  ]
}
```

And then you can grab the length of your quotes array like any other array.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're reading a file, i.e: `file.json` and the string is stored into a variable.

You can parse, get the keys as an array and use the attribute `length`.

```js
var fileStr = '{  "quote1":"texthere", "quote2":"texthere", "quote3":"texthere", "quote4":"texthere"}';

var length = Object.keys(JSON.parse(fileStr)).length;

console.log(length);
```