# Counting words not chars in array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I return this array from a laravel function:

```
 $arr = json_encode(array('priority'=>$priority,'status'=>$status,'type'=>$type));
         return $arr;
```

However in my ajax I catch them like this:

```
 success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.length);
        var priority =data.priority;
         var status =data.status;
         var type = data.type;

        // $('#submenu').empty();
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        $('#output').append("<tr><td>" + priority + "</td><td>" + status + "</td><td>" + type + "</td></tr>");

        }
      },
```

The problem is that the three priority,status and type are undefined,data.length **returns 67 instead of 3**,and `console.log(data);=>returns {"priority":"priority one","status":"status one","type":"type one"}`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640190/how-to-count-json-objects is useful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `data` variable contains a string, since you probobly didn't send `content-type` header as `application/json`.

you can decode the string like this :

```
....
success: function (data) {

        console.log(data); 

        var json = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(json);

        var priority = json.priority;
        var status = json.status;
        var type = json.type;

        // $('#submenu').empty();

        $('#output').append(
            "<tr>" + 
            "<td>" + priority + "</td>" + 
            "<td>" + status   + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + type     + "</td>" +
            "</tr>"
         );

 },
 ....
```

or a better approach would be returning a JSON response from the controller :

```
   ....
   class MyController {
       ....
       public function sendReponse() {
           $data = $this->getDataSomehow();

           return response()->json($data);
       }
       ....
   }
   ....
```

Comment: it doesnt print anything

Comment: console.log(data); is undefined,IDK why

Comment: add console.log(data) after parsing the json object, to see the result

Comment: i have updated the answer, can you please tell me what you are getting in the console ?.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` you received is a string. You need to decode it, using `json_decode()` or `JSON.parse()`

Comment: console.log(data); is undefined,IDK why